# Why is CALayer's opacity value not reflected as UIView's alpha?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I created the method below as part of custom CAAnimationGroup. The method first adds itself to weak reference to a CALayer assigned at initialization.

Then it iterates over it's own `animations` array and applies each animation 's `toValue` to the associated `keyPath` using **KVC** on the weak CALayer reference.

```
final public class FAAnimationGroup : CAAnimationGroup {

    weak var weakLayer : CALayer?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        animations = [CAAnimation]()
        fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        removedOnCompletion = true
    }

    override public func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let animationGroup = super.copyWithZone(zone) as! FAAnimationGroup
        animationGroup.weakLayer = weakLayer
        return animationGroup
    }

    ......

    func applyFinalState() {
         guard let animationLayer = weakLayer else {
             return
         }

         animationLayer.addAnimation(self, forKey: self.animationKey)

         if let groupAnimations = animations {
             for animation in groupAnimations {
                 if let toValue = animation.toValue {
                     animationLayer.setValue(toValue, forKeyPath: animation.keyPath!)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

So everything works accordingly for bounds, size, transform, and alpha for all my views just as expected with the current `removedOnCompletion` flag and `fillMode` values.

Once the animation is complete, I query the UIView, and it's backing layer. What is see is the frame reflects the correct result, the view's alpha reflects the animated opacity value. Great!

But here comes the fun part. When animation the opacity of a UISlider from 0.0 to 1.0. Once the animation is complete, I begin to adjust the UISlider value, and right as I move it, the alpha goes back to 0.0.

I tried to set the `removedCompletion` flag to **false**, and as expected, keeping the animation around kept the layer in it's final state, but that is not what I wanted. I need it to remove itself after finishing, since I did set the values directly on the the backing layer.

So after setting the `removedCompletion` back to **true**, I tried the following which has me completely stumped leading up to my question....

```
.....

if let groupAnimations = animations {
    for animation in groupAnimations {
        if let toValue = animation.toValue {

            if animation.keyPath! == "opacity" {
                 animationLayer.owningView()!.setValue(toValue, forKeyPath: "alpha")
            } else {
                 animationLayer.setValue(toValue, forKeyPath: animation.keyPath!)
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

In the code above, I would, instead of setting opacity on the layer, I set the alpha value on the owningView associated with animating layer (aka the layer's delegate). In this instance everything worked accordingly, I adjusted the slider and it did not reset to alpha 0.0

The fact that this is happening only with a UISlider is possibly irrelevant. I thought that by setting the UIView's properties, the backing layer will reflect the equivalent, and I assumed the vice versa to also be true.

**Question**

Why are the final alpha/opacity values in sync when I set the alpha of the view, but not reflected when I set the opacity on it's backing layer? What is the relationship between UIView and CALayer in this specific example?

From what I understood the two are very intricately interlinked, the UIView is kind of a wrapper full of access to the backing layer which redraws itself accordingly. What is this opacity/alpha relationship in the context of animations?